# Why the train loss and train acc never change about the GNCNN (Gaussian-Neuron CNN)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

This is my first time to train a model myself, and I have some serious problem.
I know this problem has already been discussed here.

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-the-train-loss-and-train-acc-never-change/101334

But I still can't fix it.

My code has slightly changed a little compared to the original one, but the problems are the same as description below.

Problem:
The code can run but the train loss and train acc never change
train_loss = 0.69, train_acc = 0.5.
I think the model does not be trained, but I can’t find my fault.
I try all solution I can find, change lr, reset_parameters, normalize and so on.

Maybe the preprocessing? The image are Gray image

```
COVER = 1
STEGO = 0

class CustomImageDataset(Dataset):
    # [
    #  (path_0, label_0),
    #  ...
    #  (path_n, label_n)
    # ] tuple

    def __init__(self, img_dir): #training_dataset & testing_dataset
        self.data = []

        self.readData(img_dir + '/cover_png', COVER)
        self.readData(img_dir + '/stego_png', STEGO)
        print(self.data)

    def readData(self, path, label):
        file_names = os.listdir(path)
        for file_name in file_names:
            file_path = path + '/' + file_name
            self.data.append((file_path, label))
            
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img_path, label = self.data[idx]
        image = read_image(img_path)
        return image, label

def gaussian1(x):
 mean = torch.mean(x)
 std = torch.std(x)
 return torch.exp(-((x-mean)**2)/(torch.std(x))**2) 
def gaussian2(x):
  mean = torch.mean(x)
  std = torch.std(x)
  return 0.5 * torch.exp(-((x-mean)**2)/(torch.std(x))**2) 

KV = torch.tensor([[-1,2,-2,2,-1],
      [2,-6,8,-6,2],
      [-2,8,-12,8,-2],
      [2,-6,8,-6,2],
      [-1,2,-2,2,-1]])/12.
KV = KV.view(1,1,5,5).to(device=device, dtype=torch.float)
KV = torch.autograd.Variable(KV, requires_grad=False)

class GNCNN(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(GNCNN, self).__init__()
    self.gaussian1 = gaussian1
    self.gaussian2 = gaussian2
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 16, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=0, bias=True)
    self.avg_pool1 = nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)

    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=0, bias=True)
    self.avg_pool2 =nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)

    self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(16, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=0, bias=True)
    self.avg_pool3 = nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=0)

    self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(16, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=0, bias=True)

    self.avg_pool4 = nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=0)

    self.conv5 = nn.Conv2d(16, 16, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=0, bias=True)
    self.avg_pool5 = nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=0)

    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16*4*4, 128)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 128)
    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(128, 2)
    self.reset_parameters()

  
  def forward(self, x):
    prep = F.conv2d(x, KV, padding=2) # preprocessing
    out = self.avg_pool1(gaussian1(self.conv1(prep)))
    out = self.avg_pool2(gaussian2(self.conv2(out)))
    out = self.avg_pool3(gaussian2(self.conv3(out)))
    out = self.avg_pool4(gaussian2(self.conv4(out)))
    out = self.avg_pool5(gaussian2(self.conv5(out)))
    out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)
    out = F.relu(self.fc1(out))
    out = F.relu(self.fc2(out))
    out = self.fc3(out)
    return out

  def reset_parameters(self):
    for mod in self.modules():
      if isinstance(mod, nn.Conv2d):
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.conv1.weight)
      elif isinstance(mod, nn.Linear):
        nn.init.kaiming_normal_(mod.weight.data)

def accuracy(outputs, labels):
  _, argmax = torch.max(outputs, 1)
  return (labels == argmax.squeeze()).float().mean()
    
def default_loader(path):
  try:
    img = Image.open(path)
    return img.convert('RGB') 
  except:
    print("Cannot read image: {}".format(path))

def train_model(model, criterion, optimizer, num_epochs,  batch_size, use_gpu):
  since = time.time()

  best_model_wts = model.state_dict()
  best_acc = 0.0

  val_acc_history = []
  val_loss_history = []
  is_best = False
  for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    begin_time = time.time()
    print('Epoch {}/{}'.format(epoch, num_epochs - 1))
    print('-' * 10)

    count_batch = 0

    epoch_loss = 0.
    epoch_accuracy = 0.
    running_loss = 0.
    running_accuracy = 0.
    val_loss = 0.
    val_accuracy = 0.
    test_loss = 0.
    test_accuracy = 0.

    for inputs, labels in train_dataloader:
    #  print(inputs[0].shape)
    # for data in train_loader:
    #   # count_batch += 1
    #   inputs, labels = data

      inputs = inputs.float()
      if use_gpu:
        inputs = Variable(inputs.cuda())
        labels = Variable(labels.cuda())
      else:
        inputs, labels = Variable(inputs), Variable(labels)
      
      
      optimizer.zero_grad()
      
      outputs = model(inputs)
      ###
      accuracys = accuracy(outputs, labels).item()
      print("accuracy = ", accuracys)
      running_accuracy += accuracys
      epoch_accuracy += accuracys
      ###
      loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
      running_loss += loss.item()
      epoch_loss += loss.item()
      loss.backward()
      optimizer.step()

    print("epch loss = ", epoch_loss)
    epoch_loss /= (train_sizes/batch_size)
    train_loss_history.append(epoch_loss)
    print("epch acc = ", epoch_accuracy)
    #epoch_accuracy /= train_sizes
    epoch_accuracy /= (train_sizes / batch_size)
    
    train_acc_history.append(epoch_accuracy)
    print('\nTrain: Epoch [{}] Loss: {:.4f} Acc: {:.4f}%'.format(epoch, epoch_loss, 100*epoch_accuracy))
    print('\nTrain: Epoch [{}] Loss: {:.4f}'.format(epoch, epoch_loss))

if __name__ == '__main__':

  use_gpu = torch.cuda.is_available()
  

  batch_size = 10
  learning_rate = 0.001



  # atransforms = transforms.Compose([
  #   transforms.Resize((256, 256)),
  #   transforms.Grayscale(1),
  #   # transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
  #   transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
  #   transforms.ToTensor(),
  #   transforms.Normalize([0.485, ], [0.229, ])
  # ])

  training_dataset = CustomImageDataset('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Topic_Research/toy_BOSSBase/train')
  testing_dataset = CustomImageDataset('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Topic_Research/toy_BOSSBase/test')
  train_sizes = len(training_dataset)
  print(train_sizes)

  train_dataloader = DataLoader(training_dataset, batch_size, shuffle=True)
  test_dataloader = DataLoader(testing_dataset, batch_size, shuffle=True)

  model = GNCNN()
  ################
  #model.reset_parameters()


  if use_gpu:
    model = model.cuda()


  criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss().cuda()


  optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr = learning_rate, momentum=0.9)

  train_acc_history = []
  train_loss_history = []

  model = train_model(model=model, criterion=criterion, optimizer=optimizer,
                      num_epochs=10, batch_size=batch_size, use_gpu=use_gpu)
```

> We are using the BOSSbase_1.01 dataset,HUGO algorithm 0.4bpp and 8000
> train set, 2000 val set, epoch = 50 but always get train_acc = 50% and
> train_loss = 69% [our result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwYH9.jpg)

Comment: Sorry, I'm really confused. Since from your image, the first two epochs seem good, the loss reduced from 0.72 to 0.69, so why you said that the loss didn't change.

Comment: Sorry for making you confused about our image. The loss is always about 0.72~0.69, it didn't reduce after 50 epochs, but it did change.